# ansible: task order based on extra-vars file

Tags: ansible

I have ansible playbook with 10 tasks. order of the tasks differs based on use case so I have to create extraVar.yml file for each use case and extraVar.yml will have order of the tasks defined. how to do that.

Example:

playbook:

```
tasks:
  - name task1

  - name task2

  - name task3
```

extravar.yml

```
#order of tasks
task3
task1
task2
```

Answer (score 2):

This feels like a total antipattern put you could but your tasks in to seperate task files and then iterate over the list of tasks and include those task files. Since your iterating over the list they will be imported in the order of the list.

If you change the order of the vars in the tasks variable, the order of the tasks will change

**VAR FILE**

```yaml
---
tasks:
  - task2
  - task3
  - task1
```

**Sample task file**

```yaml
---
- debug:
    msg: this is task1
```

**Playbook**

```yaml
---

- name: Creating the multi users with a new approach
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - extravars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Run task
      include_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
      loop: "{{ tasks }}"
```

**OUTPUT**

```bash
TASK [Run task] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 23 October 2022  14:31:13 +0100 (0:00:01.094)       0:00:01.205 ********
included: /local/task2.yml for localhost => (item=task2)
included: /local/task3.yml for localhost => (item=task3)
included: /local/task1.yml for localhost => (item=task1)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 23 October 2022  14:31:14 +0100 (0:00:00.159)       0:00:01.365 ********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is task2"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 23 October 2022  14:31:14 +0100 (0:00:00.047)       0:00:01.412 ********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is task3"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 23 October 2022  14:31:14 +0100 (0:00:00.045)       0:00:01.458 ********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is task1"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Sunday 23 October 2022  14:31:14 +0100 (0:00:00.068)       0:00:01.527 ********
===============================================================================
gather_facts ------------------------------------------------------------ 1.09s
debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.16s
include_tasks ----------------------------------------------------------- 0.16s
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
total ------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.42s
```

for an extra bonus point you could even pass the task order in at runtime and it will override any order that was in the vars file

`ansible-playbook main.yml -e '{"tasks": ["task3", "task1", "task2"]}'`

Comment: Thx. does this require each task in saperate file? I have to have all tasks in same yml file.

Comment: Yes seperate files, why do they have to all be in the same file?

Comment: I have 30 tasks and its order varies based on use case. It would clean if all tasks are in 1 file.

Comment: Thats not possible in ansible, tasks are run in order from top to bottom, if you have them in a single file you cannot change the order of how they execute. if some tasks always happen togeth you could group them into a task file, but if you really want to be able to change the order of things then thats the only way. If you mean you have some tasks that shouldnt run etc then you could use tags but you still cant change the order if they are all in the same file

Comment: Can you give a reasonable example where you would want to run tasks in one order then a use case where you would want to run them in a different order. This feels like an `XY` problem or its your homework exercise

Comment: example is tasks to restore protocol A, B, C, D.....Z and they are defined in 1 yml file. in some uses case, I have to execute them in C,B,D,A....Z order and in some use case I have to execute them in different order. this is problem at work i am trying to solve, it is not home work :)

Comment: Ok well as i said there is no way in ansible to change the order of tasks in the same task block. They run from top to bottom

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution

Comment: However again your lack of detail really makes it difficult, Are these really different tasks, or just the same task run with different parameters. If thats the case you could write the task once and pass in the parameters that you need iterated over from a variable. Does each task A, B, C do the same thing just with different values? or they are totally seperate things like A is some db call, B is some file update etc?

Comment: NO. each of these are completely different tasks and yes, they are completely saperate things like A is some db call, B is some file update etc.

Comment: then is sounds like they do belong in separate files then to split out the functionality and make it easily reusable.

Comment: This looks like an absolute [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info). There are many ways to run tasks in a certain order and make them dependent one upon the other among which role dependency, handlers.... IMO you are trying to solve this with the wrong pattern and since you're only asking about the expected solution there is little chances you will get a correct answer. Try to add more context and explain with more details what you are exactly trying to do. And please don't do that in comments: [edit] your answer.

Comment: Thanks!!! I am not able to add context to edit your answer. it is giving me queue full error.

I have ansible playbook below tasks:

    tasks:
      - name task1: shut uplink interface
      - name task2: shut bgp
      - name task3: shut downlink interface

goal is to have all tasks in same ansible playbook if possible and dynamically change the order of tasks depending on use case. how to do that?

Comment: @user17314281 Why edit the answer? [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create the generic playbook. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb_generic.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 1
    - debug:
        msg: 2
    - debug:
        msg: 3
```

Create the file with the order of the tasks. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat extravar.yml
1
2
0
```

The playbook below reads the generic playbook, creates the list of tasks, and writes a new playbook *pb_order.yml*

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    order_of_tasks: "{{ lookup('file', 'extravar.yml').splitlines() }}"
    pb_generic: "{{ lookup('file', 'pb_generic.yml')|from_yaml }}"
    list_of_tasks: |
      [
      {% for i in order_of_tasks %}
      {{ pb_generic.0.tasks[i|int] }},
      {% endfor %}
      ]
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/pb_order.yml"
        content: |
          - {{ pb_generic.0|combine({'tasks': list_of_tasks})|
                            to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat pb_order.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: 2
  - debug:
      msg: 3
  - debug:
      msg: 1
```

The created playbook will run the tasks in the required order.